# Using proxy_pass to forward http requests based on headers

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using a combination of ip6tables and nginx to process http requests from clients. The nginx server listens on port 8081 and must forward a request after examining the header.

Clients can send two types of requests:

1. GET/POST with no headers. These should be re-directed to **https://jaguar.mydomain.com**
2. GET/POST with specific header **elb-jaguar.mydomain.com**. These should be redirected to **https://elb-jaguar.mydomain.com**

When run as `nginx -c /home/build/v6-only.conf`, nginx fails because one `server{}` directive already has `listen` on port `8081`

`nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for [::]:8081 in /etc/nginx/v6/v6-only.conf:13`

My config is as below:

```
server {
    listen [::]:8081 ssl ipv6only=on;
    server_name elb-jaguar.mydomain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/elb.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/elb.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://elb-jaguar.mydomain.com:443;
    }
}

server {
    listen [::]:8081 ssl ipv6only=on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/regular.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/regular.key;
    server_name jaguar.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://jaguar.mydomain.com:443;
    }
}
```

How can I fix the above config to get the desired forwarding with `proxy_pass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to see because that setup *should* work.

But looking closer at the [NGINX docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) and your need for IPv6 only, it says (**my emphasis**):

> ipv6only=on|off
>
> this parameter (0.7.42) determines (via the IPV6_V6ONLY socket option) whether an IPv6 socket listening on a wildcard address [::] will accept only IPv6 connections or both IPv6 and IPv4 connections. This parameter is turned on by default. **It can only be set once on start**.

Because the error message complains of 'duplicate listen options', not 'already listening on that port' or similar, it suggests it is complaining about trying to set `ipv6only` a second time (even to the same value).

Also, it does say *This parameter is turned on by default*, so you could easily just remove it altogether, if only to try it.

Comment: Another loosely related thought: You only need separate `server` blocks because you have different SSL certs for the subdomains.  If there was an option to use a wildcard cert, you could cover both (and more) with the one cert and therefore have a single `server` block for both domains (then `proxy_pass https://$host:443$request_uri;`)